# How to start a new activity from a fragment calss by clicking on Linearlayout within fragment? below is my code but this is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

when i click on linearlayout within a fragment it dose't give any error but do not start new activity. Is there any error in my code? please someone help me. 
This fragment xml file code of my project.

Fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lbid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/pbb"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bidonpb"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bid on"
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Lap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/pbap"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:progress="60"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/appb"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Awaiting Payments"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/pbo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:progress="20"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/opb"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Overdue"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/LA"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:id="@+id/pba"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"

                android:progress="45"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/assignedpb"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Assigned"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This fragment java class code of my project.

**FragmentOne.java**

```js
  info.androidhive.listviewfeed;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        LinearLayout lbid =(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Lbid);

        lbid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProjectDetails.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post manifest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem in your `onCreateView()` method. You return

```
  return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

which makes a new view without the listener you added. You should do

```
return view;
```

because view is the one that contains the layout with the listener you added.

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day. I have already wasted one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with your intent.

//like this
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);